# Reading XML file with VB.Net XmlDocument.SelectNodes method yields count of zero

Tags: xml, vb.net

I am a novice both to coding and XML files and am trying to read the details from an XML file. Here is a sample file that I am testing with:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<mailmanager xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <locations>
    <store id="c35e549f-ffb8-4828-8290-d66c2f9b735f">
      <type>msg</type>
      <description>Volkswagen</description>
      <folder>G:\Volkswagen</folder>
    </store>
    <store id="814e7584-9f99-40a6-8520-3f5d467ea8d9">
      <type>msg</type>
      <description>Nissan</description>
      <folder>G:\Nissan</folder>
    </store>
    <store id="51d60458-01ac-421d-8fb8-3663f5963fbf">
      <type>msg</type>
      <description>Ford</description>
      <folder>G:\Ford</folder>
    </store>
    <store id="581d96c6-ea30-4301-b83b-d80473d18399">
      <type>msg</type>
      <description>Toyota</description>
      <folder>G:\Toyota</folder>
    </store>
    <store id="888eaace-9486-41db-a4ad-a21d570b0f35">
      <type>msg</type>
      <description>Tesla</description>
      <folder>G:\Tesla</folder>
    </store>
    <store id="44a6eaea-979c-4340-8a1d-1142507c42a0">
      <type>msg</type>
      <description>Fiat</description>
      <folder>G:\Fiat</folder>
    </store>
  </locations>
</mailmanager>
```

What I'm finding is that whilst I can inspect **m_xmld** with in debug (using Visual Studio) and can see that it shows the DocumentElement name as "mailmanager", which seems correct, the object **m_nodelist** has a count of zero, so the code in the For Each loop is skipped. Any idea where I am going wrong?

```vb
Private Sub LoadXMLToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LoadXMLToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim GUID As String
    Dim sType As String
    Dim sDescription As String
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim arr As String() = New String(3) {}
    Dim arListItem As ListViewItem

    Dim m_xmld As XmlDocument
    Dim m_nodelist As XmlNodeList
    Dim m_node As XmlNode

    ''Create the columns for the listview
    ListView1.Columns.Add("GUID", 600)
    ListView1.Columns.Add("Description", 100)
    ListView1.Columns.Add("Path", 70)
    ListView1.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Details
    Application.DoEvents()

    m_xmld = New XmlDocument
    m_xmld.Load("c:\temp\testing2.xml")

    'Get the list of name nodes 
    m_nodelist = m_xmld.SelectNodes("/locations/store")

    'Loop through the nodes
    For Each m_node In m_nodelist
        'Get GUID
        GUID = m_node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("id").Value
        'Get the Description Attribute Value
        sDescription = m_node.ChildNodes.Item(1).InnerText
        'Get the Path Element Value
        sPath = m_node.ChildNodes.Item(2).InnerText


        ''Add a row to the listview
        arr(0) = sType
        arr(1) = sDescription
        arr(2) = sPath
        arListItem = New ListViewItem(arr)
        ListView1.Items.Add(arListItem)
        Application.DoEvents()
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: `m_xmld.SelectNodes("mailmanager/locations/store")`. Set `Option Strict ON`, you have a bunch of problems there because this option is `OFF`. -- `GUID` is a very bad name and you're probably mixing it with `sType`. -- Remove `Application.DoEvents()`. `arr()` is useless, just `Dim arListItem = New ListViewItem({sType, sDescription, sPath})`. Declare you're locals where needed. etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using a XDocument over an XmlDocument. You can find the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument

You would then get the various `<store>` elements by calling the Descendants method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.descendants

Take a look at this example:

```vb
Dim m_xmld = XDocument.Load("testing2.xml")
Dim m_nodelist = m_xmld.Descendants("store")

For Each m_node In m_nodelist
    ListView1.Items.Add(New ListViewItem({
        m_node.Attribute("id").Value,
        m_node.Element("description").Value,
        m_node.Element("folder").Value
    }))
Next
```

Example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Kd8gQd

Comment: Thanks David, this is not compiling and I'm getting "Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Add' can be called with these arguments:" on the line that reads ListView1.Items.Add

Comment: @MaxHeadroom - that has to do with adding the ListView item. I'm not in a position to test it, but I did edit my answer.

Comment: Solved that last problem by assembling the ListView items separately. i.e. 
        For Each m_node In m_nodelist

            arr(0) = m_node.Attribute("id").Value
            arr(1) = m_node.Element("description").Value
            arr(2) = m_node.Element("folder").Value
            arListItem = New ListViewItem(arr)
            ListView1.Items.Add(arListItem)

            Application.DoEvents()
        Next